# Writing a non-minimally coupled Einstein-Maxwell action

Tags: general-relativity, variational-principle, action

Usually you study a GR system with an electromagnetic field using the standard action
\begin{equation}
S=\int{(R-\frac{1}{4}F^2)\sqrt{-g} d^4 x}
\end{equation}
(where $F_{\mu\nu}=A_{\mu,\nu}-A_{\nu,\mu}$)which you then use to derive e.o.m. and the like. The coupling between gravity and the electromagnetic field arises from the $\sqrt{-g}$ factor.

I was trying to come up with a theory with a different (non-minimal) coupling, and I've thought of a few ways to do it. For example
\begin{equation}
S=\int{(R-\frac{1}{4}F^2(1+f(R)))\sqrt{-g} d^4 x}
\end{equation}
where $f(R)$ is a generic function of the ricci scalar or
\begin{equation}
S=\int{(R-\frac{1}{4}F^2+a\times A^2R+b\times R_{\mu\nu}A^\mu A^\nu)\sqrt{-g} d^4 x}
\end{equation}
with $a, b$ being coupling constants.

Now, this is just a theoretical question about the physics of the problem, I've worked out the e.o.m. and the mathematical parts, but was wondering if anyone could come up with a physical reason to study one of the actions over one of the others, or if I'm doing something wrong in assuming these actions are valid. What are the differences, physically, between the theories described by these actions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity

Comment: First, can the last Lagrangian be made gauge invariant in $A$ for some nontrivial values of $a$ and $b$? Second, the question of whether these actions are 'valid' or not is not very meaningful. Maybe the new actions you have describe the physics of our universe in some circumstances, but we don't know for certain. Minimal coupling works well in many cases, but non-minimally coupled Lagrangians are interesting in their own right - for instance f(R) theories are basically scalar-tensor theories of gravity. Experiments then help in ruling out the various extensions of gravity.